# Github : Automated tagging on Merging of Pull Requests

Tags: github, pull-request, git-post-receive, git-tag

Is there a way to trigger an automatic, custom tagging of a repository every time a pull request is merged in github ?  for example...

After merging "pull request 8", id like to automatically tag the repository at that state as "$Major_Version.$pr_id".

The result might be "0.1.8".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Worst case, if someone hasn't written a thing to do that yet, is to use the post-receive webhooks https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks

You'd need an internet-visible web server to do this, and some code to recognize the merge (it will have two parents) and see if it mentions a pull-request.

Comment: Yup, thats definetly an option.  Was hoping i wouldnt have to maintain something like that though .